# Django, lose the variables of a template when I call the extended template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have a django project and an random app, a `homepage.html` in `localhost:8000/`, a `base.html` with a path url: `/base/some_id`, an extended `template1.html` with url: `/base/some_id/template1`.

```html
<!-- base.html -->

<body>
    <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    <a href="{% url 'template1' some_id %}">BUTTON</a>
    {% block content%} {% endblock %}
</body>
```

```html
<!-- template1.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>some text here</p>
{% endblock %}
```

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'homepage'),
    path('base/<int:some_id>/',views.base, name = 'base'),
    path('base/<some_id>/template1/', views.template1, name = 'template1'),
]
```

```py
# views.py

def base(request,some_id):
  context = {
    "message": "Hello",
    "some_id": some_id,
  }
  return render(request, "base.html", context)

def template1(request,some_id):
  return render(request, "base.html", { "newmessage": "some text" } )
```

My page base.html is correctly displayed, but when I click to the  tag to go to template1, I get a message:
`Reverse for 'template1' with arguments '('',)' not found....`

I've tried many things but nothing worked. I think my issue is that the variable `some_id` doesn't have any value in template anymore.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: You need to change your `<some_id>` to `<int:some_id>`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've already tried this one, but have the same problem again...! If it's helpful the error I'm taking from my logs is "GET /base/1/template1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 149411